# Transform multiple php arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create a set of arrays that look like this:

```
Array ([ID] => 55 [status] => u [resvdate] => 07/16/2018 [price] => 119.00 [source] => C) 
Array ([ID] => 56 [status] => u [resvdate] => 07/17/2018 [price] => 119.00 [source] => C) 
Array ([ID] => 57 [status] => u [resvdate] => 07/18/2018 [price] => 119.00 [source] => C)
```

from five arrays that look like this:

```
Array ( [resvdate1] => 07/16/2018 [resvdate2] => 07/17/2018 [resvdate3] => 07/18/2018 ) 
Array ( [resvdateid1] => 55 [resvdateid2] => 56 [resvdateid3] => 57 ) 
Array ( [resvprice1] => 119.00 [resvprice2] => 119.00 [resvprice3] => 119.00 ) 
Array ( [pricesource1] => C [pricesource2] => C [pricesource3] => C ) 
Array ( [rowstatus1] => u [rowstatus2] => u [rowstatus3] => u )
```

Do I just need to loop through each array and pick off the values or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: This is not valid PHP array syntax. And can you explain _how_ the data should map from the inputs to the desired output. I would not want to assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a go at it:

```
$data = [
  [
    "resvdate1" => "07/16/2018",
    "resvdate2" => "07/17/2018",
    "resvdate3" => "07/18/2018"
  ],
  [
    "resvdateid1" => 55, 
    "resvdateid2" => 56,
    "resvdateid3" => 57
  ],
  [
    "resvprice1" => "119.00",
    "resvprice2" => "119.00",
    "resvprice3" => "119.00"
  ],
  [
    "pricesource1" => "C", 
    "pricesource2" => "C", 
    "pricesource3" => "C"
  ],
  [
    "rowstatus1" => "u",
    "rowstatus2" => "u",
    "rowstatus3" => "u"
  ]
];

$keys = [
  "resvdate" => "resvdate",
  "resvdateid" => "id",
  "resvprice" => "price",
  "pricesource" => "source",
  "rowstatus" => "status"
];
$result = [];

foreach ($data as $a) {
  $i = 0;

  foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $result[$i++][$keys[preg_replace("/\d/", "", $k)]] = $v;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [resvdate] => 07/16/2018
            [id] => 55
            [price] => 119.00
            [source] => C
            [status] => u
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [resvdate] => 07/17/2018
            [id] => 56
            [price] => 119.00
            [source] => C
            [status] => u
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [resvdate] => 07/18/2018
            [id] => 57
            [price] => 119.00
            [source] => C
            [status] => u
        )

)
```

### Explanation

This is basically a column to row mapping involving a little key adjustment along the way.